# Find the derivatives given function and derivative values

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm confused at how to answer this question. I am needing to find both derivatives given these functions and values. Help please!

> Suppose $F(x) = f(x^8)$, $G(x) = (f(x))^8$ and
>   $a^7 = 8$, $f(a) = 3$, $f'(a) = 5$, $f'(a^8) = 4$.
>
> Find: $F'(a)$ and $G'(a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to use the chain rule.

For example, we can give $x^8$ a name, say $g(x)=x^8$. Now we have $F(x)=f(g(x))$. Using the chain rule to take the derivative, the rest is just a matter of substitutions: $$F'(a)=f'(g(a))g'(a)=f'(a^8)\cdot 8a^7=4\cdot 8\cdot 8 = 256$$

The process for finding $G'(a)$ is very similar.

Comment: to find G'(a): Would I do G'(x) = 8(f(x))^7*(f'(x))? Therefore G'(a) = 8(3)^7(5) = 87480?

Comment: At a glance, that looks correct to me!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $F(x) = f(x^8)$, then $F'(x) = f'(x^8)*(8x^7)$.